# On change of account owner, its opportunity owner will also get change

Tags: apex, trigger, workflow

Could you please let me know if its possible to change the opportunity owner when the owner of account changes with using Workflow.or the only way to achieve this is through trigger.

Can you please help and let me know how it can be done

Thanks in Advance, 
Ankita

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is native Salesforce functionality. If any opportunity which has AccountId NOT empty and that Account owner is changed then Salesforce automatically changes owner of Opportunity.

So, Owner of Account will always the Owner of its underlined Opportunities. That's default behaviour, no trigger or workflow needed.